# Kids funny short book. Involves a troop of boy scouts who go camping and meet an alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

I listened to an eight year old read this kids book to me. He had brought it home from school to read. It had lots of illustrations which the kid loved showing to me. I think the cover may have been green. The book was paperback. I think the title was a sentence, not a single word.

A group of boy scouts go camping and meet a humanoid alien.

This was about 2021 in the UK.

I have ruled out some books that have both aliens and boy scouts.

It is not *The Space Ship Under the Apple Tree* by Louis Slobodkin.

It is not *Farmer in the Sky*. Nor is it *Tenderfoot in Space*. These are both by Robert Heinlein.

Comment: Thank you for providing some items you've ruled out. That can help. Do you remember anything about what the aliens looked like? Did they speak English? Mostly humanoid? Did they bargain, alien technology (toys for the alien) for snacks and toys from the scouts?

Comment: Probably also not [*Scouts*](https://goodreads.com/book/show/42396820-scouts), which is too long.

Comment: I am beginning to doubt my memory about the length so I will delete that from my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Sorry I do not remember if they spoke English or traded things with the scouts.

Comment: I just read a review of Scouts. This is not the book I remember. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you remember if the alien was humanoid?

Comment: Yes, the alien was humanoid.

Comment: Thanks to your questions I have found the book.  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9663843-ging-gang-goolie-its-an-alien. Will write an answer later.

Comment: Excellent! :-D Honestly, I find a lot of self-answers by trying to track down details. Usually, it's entirely self-imposed, but running through the checklist for [tag:story-identification] can be nice too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks to Fuzzy Boots' questions in comments I have found the book.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9663843-ging-gang-goolie-its-an-alien